# jQuery not reading or counting nodes of XML file correctly

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<Root>
<Row>
<title>Homeward Bound</title>
</Row>
<Row>
<title>Escape to Witch Mountain</title>
</Row>
....
....
</Root>
```

My jQuery to read the XML is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var data;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "titles.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (e) {
        data = e;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("The XML File could not be processed correctly.");
    }
});
alert($(data).find("Root Row").length);
```

...
..
.

The alert shows 0 - despite there being several records.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm reading the XML file - or is it my ".find" that is wrong?

Thanks for any help, Mark

Comment: you are using `alert` outside the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope of success argument remains in method only. set value variable to variable and then use the variable outside. or write the code in success function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "titles.xml",
 dataType: "xml",
 success: function (e) {
    alert($(data).find("Root Row").length);
 },
 error: function() {
    alert("The XML File could not be processed correctly.");
 }});
 });
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply.  It still shows 0 however. Is my XML file ok? - thank you, Mark

Comment: @mark: that is because ajax call is not completed when the alert is fired.